# History of “Daridrya Dahan ShivaStotram”

Tags: shiva, stotra, vashishta

Sage Vashistha created this beautiful stotram in praise of lord Shiva. You can read it in Sanskrit on this website https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_shiva/daaridryadahan.html?lang=sa

And, the stotra translated into English can be read from [here](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Daridrya_Dahana_Shiva_Stotram).

**I would like to know in what condition or situation sage Vashistha wrote this?**

For e.g when Ravana created Shiva tandava stotram, he was praising Shiva for mercy as he was being crushed under Kailasha. Similarly, is there any background about this stotram?

Comment: Sage Vasistha belongs to Rig Vedic era (Mandala 7). At that point of time,   Shiva that we know,  husband of Uma, holder of Thrishula,  one who resides in Kailasa,etc, did not emerge .  Rig Vedic Rudra is one of the epithets like Vishnu or Indra, etc,  of Almighty. Someone at a later date might have composed it in the name of sage Vasistha .

Comment: Is Sage Vashistha of Rig Vedic era is different from Sage Vashistha from Ramayana? During the time of Ramayan, people knew about the Shiva (holder of Trishula who resides in kailasha) right? @srimannarayanakv  thanks

Comment: No.  Ramayana was composed in the post Vedic period and especially when Yajurveda was given the importance.  The physical Yagna had been propagated in Yajurveda, whereas in Rig Veda it is mind related.  Sri Rama was described as an expert in Yajurveda - yajurveda vinItasya (sundara Kanda) @Ketan

Comment: We can't say for sure whether Rig Vedic Vasistha was the same as Vasistha of Ramayana.  There was no enimity between them in Rig Veda, whereas in Ramayana , it was described so. Shiva appears in Yuddha Kanda as one of the TRINITY, after the episode of Sita parityAga is over.  It is an [interpolated story](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/8851/3869) @Ketan

Comment: @srimannarayanakv look at this answer https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/22303/8735. It has reference from Vedas that confirms Vedic Shiva was known very similar to how we know him today. He has blue throat, matted hair, lives in kailasha, husband of Uma. If that is true, then Vedic Vashistha could have composed this stotra. What do you think

Comment: Sorry my friend,  the answers did not contain reference to Rig veda proper.   By the way, the main answers were posted long back when the rules of the site were not strict enough as they have become now. It is true that Rudra namakam is available in Yajurveda, which the answers were referring to.   However, as far as I know, the core Veda is referred to as Rigood veda only.   The only mantra that was taken and adopted in Namakam  from Rig Veda is **"Triambakam yajamahe ......"**.  You have every right to differ with my opinion. @Ketan

Comment: The following sloka was mentioned in 2 of the answers - कैलासशिखरे रम्ये शंकरस्य शुभे गृहे ।
देवतास्तत्र मोदन्ति तन्मे मनः शिवसंकल्पमस्तु ।।. I don't think that it is from Rig veda.  Let someone else clarify this. It might be from later day literature @Ketan

Comment: @srimannarayanakv well thanks for sharing. I have not read vedas. I just know what I have read on this forum so if you say so :). Can you tell me what is best resource for reading Rigveda in English . Thanks again

Comment: Very difficult to say, as I am not an expert in the Veda.   I had expressed my views to the best of my knowledge.  Anyways,  the translation of H. H. Wilson is better than the one of Griffiths.  It doesn't mean to say translation of H. H. Wilson is the best.  Ask any expert in the veda in your area,  as the Veda is so cryptic,  it is almost impossible to ordinary people to decode it.  Only sages like Sri Ramana Maharishi can decode it.