# In the legend about Venkateswara,what is the relationship between Vedavati and Padmavati?

Tags: venkateshwara, brahmanda-purana

In the legend about Venkateswara, he marries Padmavati. There is mention about Vedavati. What is the relationship between Vedavati and Padmavati?

Comment: Vedavati (in Ramayana, Treta Yuga) is reborn as Padmavati (in Kali Yuga) - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vedavati

Comment: Refer [this answer](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/3555/3500).

Answer (score 4):

From [Skanda Purana](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/details/skandapurana22.html):

> Varaha Deva described to Bhu Devi that Emperor Akash decided to
>   perform a Grand Yagna on the banks of Arani and while tilling, he
>   found a girl child and as he was issueless, brought her up as their
>   own, named as Padmavati......
>
> **Varaha Deva narrated the background of Padmavati’s earlier birth as
>   Vedavati to Bhu Devi**. Vedavati was a companion of Devi Lakshmi and
>   when the latter became Rama’s spouse as Sita, she left for forests to
>   perform Tapasya, but demon Ravana misbehaved with her and she ended
>   her life by jumping into fire and cursed Ravana that his entire clan
>   would be wiped out because of a woman.

So,Padmavati was Vedavati in her earlier birth(as correctly said in another answer) & which was when Rama lived,i.e in the Treta Yuga.