# Did Agni Deva marry an Incarnation of Bhudevi?

Tags: ramayana, lakshmi, sita, skanda-purana, venkateshwara

As per this [answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3553/why-did-sita-have-a-past-life), Vedavati is an incarnation of Bhudevi who later went on to become Padmavati, the consort of Venkateswara. But this version of [Skanda Purana](https://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/details/skandapurana22.html) talks about Vedavati, born as Swaha, wife of Agni Deva.

> The vily Ravana dressed as a Tapsvi revealed his real form as soon as she was prevailed to cross the fiery Lakshman Rekha and forcibly took her to Lanka. After Rama killed Ravana, there was ‘Agni-Pariksha’ (Proof of Purity / by Fire), Sita came out unscathed. But the real fact was that Agni Deva hid real Sita in Patala and **Agni’s wife Swaha assumed the role of Maya Sita**; in fact Vedavati’s earlier birth was of Swaha Devi! Thus, Vedavati / Swaha turned to Maya Sita was Padmavati.

Also, the [Brahma Vaivarta Purana](https://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/brahma%20vaivartha/bookview.php?chapnum=14) mentions that Vedavathi was born as Draupadi and became the wife of Pandavas.

From the above things, we can conclude, that Swaha Devi, Vedavathi, Draupadi and Padmavati were all incarnations of Bhudevi. If Swaha Devi was an incarnation of Bhudevi. How did Agni Deva marry her ?