# How many days did Ravana keep Sita confined?

Tags: ramayana, ravana, sita

How many days did Ravana keep Sita confined?

I have searched many sites over the internet but wasn't able to find an answer to this question. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Related: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/894/36

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ravana kidnapped maa Sita in the season of *Hemanta* (comes before winter) and had given Her twelve months time to make up Her decision to accept Ravana before his demons kill Her:

> शृणु मैथिलि मत् वाक्यम् मासान् द्वादश भामिनि ||
>   कालेन अनेन न अभ्येषि यदि माम् चारु हासिनि |
>   ततः त्वाम् प्रातः आशा अर्थम् सूदाः छेत्स्यन्ति लेशशः || [VR - 3.56.24,25]
>
> **Meaning**
>   Oh, angry lady Maithili, listen to my words. A period of twelve months is given to you. And oh, smiley smiler, if you do not come nigh of me within that period, then the cooks will slice you to pieces for the purpose of a morning meal

When Hanuman met maa Sita in Panchavati (2nd September 7292 B.C.), She told him that only two months of Her life is left [VR - 5.58.106]. And just around 2 months later from the day of Hanuman's meeting with maa Sita (3rd  November 7292 B.C), the final war, to rescue maa Sita, had started.

So Ravana kept maa Sita confined for around **12 months** or roughly 365 days.

**Source:**
http://www.hindunet.org/hindu_history/ancient/ramayan/rama_vartak.html

Comment: Isn't Ramayana happened in the Treta yuga, which is about 864,000 years ago?

Comment: @aeonsleo Yeah Ramayana happened in Treta Yuga but not 864,000 years ago as I discuss [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9009/did-ramayana-occur-1-6-million-years-ago/9015#9015).

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Dwapar yuga is 864,000 years and Kaliyuga is 432,000 years. Now we are 5000 years past the start of Kaliyuga and Ramayana happened when Treta Yuga ended so its roughly 869, 000 years.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Your calculation of Yuga durations is totally misplaced. When Krishna died, Kaliyuga started and its around 5000 years ago from the present. At the end of Kaliyuga, God Kalki will be there.

Comment: @aeonsleo The theory you are referring to is mentioned in a lot of scriptures but that theory is wrong. This revelation was made by Sri Yukteswar Giri in his book "The Holy Science". Read that book to know why the traditional theory is absolutely nonsense. For more information, see my answer [here](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2220/what-is-the-duration-timeline-of-the-four-yugas/9965#9965).

Answer (score 10):

As I discuss in my [**answer here**](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15676/how-is-it-possible-for-rama-to-reach-ayodhya-in-20-days-from-dusherra/15685#15685) *Padma Purana, Patala Khanda chapter 36* gives each and every Tithi of Ramas life in detail. It states:

> दशैकाधिकमासांस्तुचतुर्दशाहानिमैथिली । 
>   उवासरामरहितारावणस्यानिवेशने ।। 
>   द्विचत्वारिंशकवर्षेरामोराज्यमकारयत । 
>  
>   **Maithill (i.e. Sita) lived without Rama in the house of Ravana for eleven months and fourteen days**. Rama ruled (i.e. was consecrated as the king) when he was forty-two years old. At that time SIta had completed thirty-three years. That lord Rama being delighted entered the city Ayodhya at the end of the fourteenth year and with his brothers ruled there.

Thus, Sita lived without Rama in the house of Ravana for **11 months and 14 days.**

Answer (score 4):

Sita was abducted probably in the Visakha month (or) Grishma Ritu, but not in Hemanth Ritu. The following paras explain that.

1. By the time Vanaras reached the ocean, they found that already Vasanta Ritu had entered.

> ते वसंतम् अनुप्राप्तम् प्रतिवेद्य परस्परम् |
>   नष्ट संदेश काल अर्था निपेतुर् धरणी तले || ४-५३-५
>
> On discussing among themselves they found that spring season has arrived, and they also found the purpose of timely messaging about Seetha to Sugreeva is lost, thus they plumped down onto the surface of earth.

---

2. Sri Hanuma reaches within a few days the Lanka and finds Sita.  While talking with him Sita says as follows:

> वर्तते दशमो मासो द्वौ तु शेषौ प्लवम्गम |
>   रावणेन नृशंसेन समयो यः कृतो मम || ५-३७-८
>
> O Hanuma! Out of the time-limit given to me by the cruel Ravana for my survival, the tenth month is now running. Only two months are left out.

---

So we can infer that Sita spent **10 months** before Sri Hanuma arrived there **and probably another month** before Ravana was eliminated, but not complete 12 months.