# Time left to rescue Sita from the day of her kidnap

Tags: ramayana, rama, sita

I have been watching Ramayana these days and the timeline of Ram's exile confuses me. (My knowledge for this question comes from the TV Serial, So please correct me If I am wrong)

As per my understanding, Sita was kidnapped by Rawan in the 13th year of their exile. That means they should be back to Ayodhya by the that year's no-moon of Katik month. (The day of Diwali).

But when Ram kills Vali and Sugreev was about to launch a search mission he said that as Monsoon time is here they should wait for 4 months and will begin the search when the month of Katik starts. That leaves only 15 days of their exile. Or am I wrong here and this indecent was actually a year earlier and they had 1 year left.

So exactly how much time was left from the day Sita was kidnapped?

Comment: why would tv writers be pundits on Ramayana?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After bringing Sita to Lanka, Ravana gives her 1 year time limit for surrendering to him.

> शृणु मैथिलि मत् वाक्यम् मासान् द्वादश भामिनि || ३-५६-२४ कालेन अनेन न
>   अभ्येषि यदि माम् चारु हासिनि | ततः त्वाम् प्रातः आशा अर्थम् सूदाः
>   छेत्स्यन्ति लेशशः || ३-५६-२५
>
> "Oh, angry lady Maithili, listen to my words. A period of twelve
>   months is given to you. And oh, smiley smiler, if you do not come nigh
>   of me within that period, then the cooks will slice you to pieces for
>   the purpose of a morning meal."

The Vanara army started their journey in Aswayuja (September - October) month.

> दर्शयन्ति शरन् नद्यः पुलिनानि शनैः शनैः | नव संगम सव्रीडा जघनानि इव
>   योषितः || ४-३०-५८
>
> "The ***autumnal rivers*** are showing their dunes slowly and slowly, as
>   with shying brides showing hips in their new trysts, slowly and
>   slowly.

The vanara troop that went in Southern direction, lead by Angada, came back in Vasantha (February-March) month.

Sita says to Sri Hanuman that only 2 months were left out of the time limit given by Ravana.

> द्वौ मासौ तेन मे कालो जीवित अनुग्रहः कृतः || ५-३३-३१ ऊर्ध्वम्
>   द्वाभ्याम् तु मासाभ्याम् ततः त्यक्ष्यामि जीवितम् |
>
> "A period of two months of survival-benefit has been given to me by
>   him. For that reason, after the said two months, I shall give up my
>   life."

As Sri Hanuman reached Lanka in Vasanta ritu, Sita might have been abducted in Chaitra month.

So 1 year might have elapsed from the day of her abduction to her regaining by Sri Rama.

After completion of the war, Sri Rama [reached Ayodhya in Chaitra month](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/35110/3869) (March - April).

Comment: Btw, do you cut / paste from Sanskrit Ramayana original or re-type it ?

Comment: Yes, copy and paste from this site (https://valmikiramayan.net/) @Narasimham

Comment: Sri Rama reached Ayodhya in Chaitra month (March - April).
But we celebrate Deepawali in the month of Katik(October-November) as the day when Shri Ram came back to Ayodhya.  Is it not so ??

Comment: I don't know how it was perceived by some people that Shri Ram came back to Ayodhya in the month of Katik(October-November), as the Ramayana clearly says that he came back in Chaitra.  In South India, people celebrate Deepavali on the occasion of Sri Krishna's win over Naraka @V.Aggarwal

Comment: @srimannarayanakv I would say that this does come as a shock to me. I would like to discuss more about it, but maybe in a separate question some other day :) .

Comment: You are welcome :-) @V.Aggarwal

Answer (score 0):

Sita was kidnapped in the second year of Exile and it took 12 Years for Rama to free Sita from Ravana.